# How do I compare two lists to a python tuple, identify items, and append value based on conditionals?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, tuples

How do I:

1. Identify which item from the dataframe df falls within each list (list1 or list2)
2. Create a new column ('new_item')
3. Determine which variable should be appended to the 'item' value and add it to the new column

Two lists of unique items:

```
list1 = ['one','two','shoes']
list2 = ['door','four','tires']
```

If item is in list1, append the following variable value to the end of the item and append it to the 'new_item' column:

```
twentysix_above = '_26+' (value is equal or greater than 26)
six_to_twentyfive = '_25'  (value is between 6 and 25)
one_to_five = '_5'  (value is between 1 and 5)
```

If item is in list2, append the following variable value to the end of each item and append it to the 'new_item' column:

```
twentyone_above = '_21+' (value is equal or greater than 21)
one_to_twenty = '_20' (value is between 1 and 20)
```

If the item isn't in either list, carry over the item name to the 'new_item' column.

Dataframe column will have one, some, or none of the 'items' from each list in it and an associated number from the 'number' column. I've gotten partially there, but I'm not sure how to compare to the other list and put that all into the 'new_item' column?  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
>> print df
    item    number
0   one     4
1   door    55
2   sun     2
3   tires   62
4   tires   7
5   water   94

>> list1 = ['one','two','shoes']
>> list2 = ['door','four','tires']
>> df['match'] = df.item.isin(list1)
>> bucket = []
>> for row in df.itertuples():
        if row.match == True and row.item > 25:
            bucket.append(row.item + '_26+')
        elif row.match == True and row.item >5:
            bucket.append(row.item + '_25')
        elif row.match == True and row.item >0:
            bucket.append(row.item +'_5')                    
        else:
            bucket.append(row.item)
        df['new_item'] = bucket

>> print df
    item    number  match   new_item
0   one     4       True    one_5
1   door    55      True    door
2   sun     2       False   sun
3   tires   62      True    tires
4   tires   7       True    tires
5   water   94      False   water
```

Desired Result: (comparing both lists and potentially not needing the boolean check column)

```
    item    number  new_item
0   one     4       one_20
1   door    55      door__21+
2   sun     2       sun
3   tires   62      tires_21
4   tires   7       tires_20
5   water   94      water
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your desired result is a bit off. The first row is in list one and has a value of 4, so it should be 'one_5' right?

Anyway, this can be accomplished with boolean masking. DataFrames have a useful isin() function making it easy to find if the value is in your lists. Then you have two more conditions, if you need a value between two numbers, or just one more condition if the range is unbounded.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['one', 'door', 'sun', 'tires', 'tires', 'water'], 
                   'number': [4, 55, 2, 62, 7, 94]})
list1 = ['one','two','shoes']
list2 = ['door','four','tires']

df['new_item'] = df['item']
logic1 = np.logical_and(df.item.isin(list1), df.number > 25)
logic2 = np.logical_and.reduce([df.item.isin(list1), df.number > 5, df.number <= 25])
logic3 = np.logical_and.reduce([df.item.isin(list1), df.number > 1, df.number <= 5])
logic4 = np.logical_and(df.item.isin(list2), df.number >= 21)
logic5 = np.logical_and.reduce([df.item.isin(list2), df.number > 1, df.number < 20])

df.loc[logic1,'new_item'] = df.loc[logic1,'item']+'_26+'
df.loc[logic2,'new_item'] = df.loc[logic2,'item']+'_25'
df.loc[logic3,'new_item'] = df.loc[logic3,'item']+'_5'
df.loc[logic4,'new_item'] = df.loc[logic4,'item']+'_21+'
df.loc[logic5,'new_item'] = df.loc[logic5,'item']+'_20'
```

And we have this as the output

[image: resulting DataFrame]

Comment: This works great!!  Thank you!!  I hadn't used 'logical_and' with numpy before, so yeah, thank you!